# How to prevent ChartJS ticks from 'jumping'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm using the zoom plugin with ChartJS and the autoSkip which calculates the best way to show labels. It's a great option and works quite well. My problem lies in that it will update the x axis tick everytime the graph moves, therefore making it quite 'jumpy'. For example, when I move into minutes ticks, one frame it will decide that 11, 11:20, 11:40 and 12 be the best to display, then the next frame it will go to 11, 11:30, 12 and then the next one it goes back to the first values.

Is there anyway I can prevent that from happening, so the ticks stay in place, as if I was actually scrolling the chart instead of updating the values every time?

Here are my options:

```
const prepareOptions = (
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
  maximumSpeed: number,
): ChartOptions<'line'> => {
  return {
    animation: false,
    parsing: false,
    responsive: true,
    interaction: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      axis: 'x',
      intersect: false,
    },
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (context: any) => `${context.dataset.label}: ${context.formattedValue} km/h`,
        },
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      decimation: {
        enabled: true,
        algorithm: 'lttb',
        samples: 500,
        threshold: 500,
      },
      zoom: {
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'x',
        },
        zoom: {
          wheel: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          mode: 'x',
        },
        limits: {
          x: {
            min: startDate.valueOf(),
            max: endDate.valueOf(),
          },
        },
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        min: startDate.valueOf(),
        max: endDate.valueOf(),
        type: 'time',
        offsetAfterAutoskip: true,
        time: {
          minUnit: 'minute',
          tooltipFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
          displayFormats: {
            day: 'dd MMM',
            second: 'HH:mm:ss',
            minute: 'HH:mm',
            hour: 'HH:mm',
          },
        },
        ticks: {
          major: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          source: 'auto',
          maxRotation: 0,
          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 10,
          stepSize: 5,
        },
        adapters: {
          date: {
            locale: pl,
          },
        },
        display: true,
      },
      y: {
        type: 'linear',
        min: 0,
        max: Math.ceil(maximumSpeed / 10) * 10,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Prędkość (km/h)',
        },
      },
    },
  };
};
```